# How to best handle mysql requests in a deno webserver

Tags: mysql, typescript, deno

I'm trying to make a mysql-based webapp based in Deno/Drash. A request comes in - it needs await a response from an sql query that is based on the path parameter - and then respond. When I try to await the query in the GET function it complains that I can't await in there (which makes sense) - is the best practice to then make the GET() function async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct! Drash supports async HTTP methods and in your case, you would want to make your GET method async.